# Is there another way to make this static function?

Tags: php

I always need to set the `$error` array in the object if there is an error because of internal specifications but i don't know if this is the best way to do it as `checkIfExistsInTable()` needs to be a static function.

```
final class Database {

    private $dbLink;

    public $hasError = false;

    public $error = [];

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $db, $username, $password, $encType = "utf8") {

        if ( in_array( strtolower($driver), PDO::getAvailableDrivers(), true) ) {

            // Create connection string !
            $dsn = "$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db";

            try {
                // New connection
                $this->dbLink = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

                // Set encType
                $this->dbLink->exec("SET NAMES $encType");

            } catch (PDOException $e) {

                $this->hasError = true;
                $this->error["code"] = 002;
                $this->error["message"] = $e->getMessage();

            }

        } else {

            $this->hasError = true;
            $this->error["code"] = 001;
            $this->error["message"] = "Couldn't find the database driver.";

        }
    }

    public static function checkIfExistsInTable(string $needle, string $haystack, string $table, Database $databaseObj):bool {

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE $haystack=:value";

        try {

            $link = $databaseObj->getDbLink();

            $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":value", $needle);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {

                return true;

            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $databaseObj->hasError = true;
            $databaseObj->error["code"] = 003;
            $databaseObj->error["message"] = "Error ocurred on " . __FUNCTION__ . ": " . $e->getMessage();

        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get PDO connection object
     *
     * @return  PDO
     */ 
    public function getDbLink()
    {
        return $this->dbLink;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, you feed a static method of a class a instantiation of itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do for the sake of my sanity:

```
final class Database {

    private $dbLink;

    public $hasError = false;

    public $error = [];

    public function __construct($driver, $host, $db, $username, $password, $encType = "utf8") {

        if ( in_array( strtolower($driver), PDO::getAvailableDrivers(), true) ) {

            // Create connection string !
            $dsn = "$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db";

            try {
                // New connection
                $this->dbLink = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

                // Set encType
                $this->dbLink->exec("SET NAMES $encType");

            } catch (PDOException $e) {

                $this->hasError = true;
                $this->error["code"] = 002;
                $this->error["message"] = $e->getMessage();

            }

        } else {

            $this->hasError = true;
            $this->error["code"] = 001;
            $this->error["message"] = "Couldn't find the database driver.";

        }
    }

    public static function checkIfExistsInTable( string $needle, string $haystack, string $table, Database $databaseObj) {
         try { 
              $databaseObj->checkIfExists($needle, $haystack, $table);
         } catch (PDOException $e) {
              return false;
         }
    }

    public function checkIfExists(string $needle, string $haystack, string $table) :bool {

        // Good practice to escape field names in case someone sends "1=1 OR field" as a field name  
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE `$haystack`=:value";

        try {

            $link = $this->getDbLink();

            $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(":value", $needle);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) {

                return true;

            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $this->hasError = true;
            $this->error["code"] = 003;
            $this->error["message"] = "Error ocurred on " . __FUNCTION__ . ": " . $e->getMessage();
            throw $e; //Rethrow

        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get PDO connection object
     *
     * @return  PDO
     */ 
    public function getDbLink()
    {
        return $this->dbLink;
    }

}
```

There's three changes here:

1. The static body was moved to a non-static. I think this makes more sense for that method
2. The non-static updates the error and rethrows it. This is generally good because keeping track of the error doesn't mean that you can actually handle it, maybe the calling function can.
3. The static method keeps its exiting behaviour but is now just a proxy to the non-static method and swallows the exception. This way you keep the class working in the exact same way but make refactoring a lot easier in the future.